# Science fiction story with a boy and girl protagonist and spider-like alien abductors

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

The story begins with the daughter of a government scientist before rockets could achieve orbit on earth, and they meet a boy's family who claims that their backwoods family jerry-rigged a satellite to go around the Earth that crashed in Mexico.

Then they are abducted by spider-like aliens, and as they travel via a wormhole it collapses and they end up outside of time briefly. This is the part that is most memorable, where they describe having been on a planet from eternity outside of time and at the same time always leaving and always arriving, it made my head hurt.

They also escape and go on more space adventures but I cannot for the life of me remember the book's name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?  How about the names of any of the characters?

Comment: @Paulie_D Not sure if it was NASA but it was some government scientist the girl's mom was a part of "She hated friction" in refrence to escaping the atmosphere

Comment: @DavidW I read it some time in 2010ish, I do not remember the cover art but it had a few illustrations per chapter in like pencil art

Comment: Larklight by Philip Reeve?

Comment: @sueelleker Post that as an answer?

Comment: @sueelleker Wow that one is incredibly similar but no, it was definitely not set in Victorian times. closer to like 1950s.

Comment: Paulie_D; I wasn't sure, because in Larklight I think the satellites were well known. (And looks like I was wrong anyway)

Answer (score 10):

I found the book, thank you all; it is [*The Doom Machine*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1408399) by Mark Teague.

Quoting the blurb on the [Scholastic site](https://www.scholastic.ca/books/view/the-doom-machine):

> With surprises around every corner, popular author Mark Teague takes readers on a funny, outrageous adventure when the small, sleepy town of Vern Hollow is invaded by a flying saucer filled with ridiculously inept aliens. When a spaceship lands in nearby Dutch Woods, juvenile delinquent Jack Creedle and prim A-student Isadora Shumway form an unexpected friendship. Jack's uncle, Bud, a witty amateur inventor with unschooled Einstein abilities, has built a spacetravel machine, and a group of hilariously bizarre space aliens are here to steal it. Despite themselves, the Skreeps manage to capture and fly away with Jack, Isadora, and Uncle BudÂ—and three other ooman bings from Uurth. Come along on a wild space voyage as our unlikely heroes try to outwit an entertaining cast of aliens who are determined to conquer Planet Earth. Readers young and old will not be able to put this book down!

Comment: It's great that you found it!  Is this a quote from somewhere (where?) or your own words?  If it's a quote you should attribute it.

Comment: You will be able to click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept, but as a self-accept, it won't let you finish the process for another 43 hours or so.

Comment: @DavidW it's a summary from the bing AI, idk how to cite that.

Comment: Ah, right.  I actually didn't catch that it was AI-generated, since AFAICT it's actually correct.  You could try quoting the [book description on the Scholastic site](https://www.scholastic.ca/books/view/the-doom-machine) instead, which, given it's from the publisher, is more authoritative.